# Detect if variable is dict / array / list

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I've the following values.yaml:

```yaml
env:
  NODES:
    value:
      - 192.168.178.1:1234
      - 192.168.178.2:1234
      - 192.168.178.3:1234
      - 192.168.178.4:1234
  PASSWORD:
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: foo
        key: bar
```

Now, in the deployment I've the following lines to specify the environment:

```yaml
          env:
            {{- range $name, $item := .Values.env }}
            - name: {{ $name }}
              {{- $item | toYaml | nindent 14 }}
            {{- end }}
```

This works as long as "NODES" is no list because they are not allowed as env variable, but I would like to specify them as list in the values.yaml. So the question is, how I can test if $item.value is a dict or a simple string.

I tried using `typeOf`, but it tells me that NODES is "[]interface {}". So I wonder what's the correct way to test?!

My goal is, if I see an array in the env of my deployment to join them using ";", e.g. `value: {{ join ";" .env.NODES.value | quote }}`.

Answer (score 5):

Helm has [some template functions to inspect object types](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#reflection-functions) (from the [Sprig support library](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/reflection.html)) but these quickly get into the underlying Go type system.

For the specific thing you're asking, you might try the Helm/Sprig `kindIs` function.  This passes through to the underlying [Go `reflect` package](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Kind) but in particular it does distinguish `slice` (list) and `map` (dict) as specific kinds.

```yaml
{{- if and $item.value (kindIs "slice" $item.value) }}
value: {{ join ";" $item.value }}
{{- end }}
```

Rather than trying to have your Helm values directly reflect the Kubernetes object structure, you might consider having configuration values like this list of nodes as top-level configuration values.

```yaml
# values.yaml
# not inside an `env:` block, at the top level
nodes:
  - 192.168.178.1:1234
  - 192.168.178.2:1234
```

Then you can construct these from a known format in your template.  This will be much more straightforward than trying to use the reflection functions.

```yaml
env:
  - name: NODES
    value: {{ join ";" .Values.nodes }}
```